Ignoramus seeking help - Mathematically describing the inverse tangent of a rotating shape
I have searched and researched for a few years without much success, so bring my question to you here in hope that it might find the right people that can help.
Suppose you have a hexagon having an inscribed diameter "d1", with said hexagon rotating about the diameter d1's origin/center. Now, suppose you want to describe a triangle, square, or pentagon that is always tangent to the hexagon at one point while said triangle ( or square or pentagon ) is ALSO rotating about the center of its own inscribed diameter, d2. < d2 is obviously not coincident or concentric with d1 >
How can this be mathematically described?
I have reduced this example down to the hexagon/triangle(square/pentagon) version to begin with. However, this ultimately should be able to be applied to any repeating geometry arranged along a diameter... ( internal & external )
Please take it slow. I'm ignorant. :) Thank you.

I understand that you are probably referring to regular triangles and other regular polygons but in view of your last remark ("ultimately") it is better to state that explictly.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please provide a diagram. In particular, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean by polygons being tangent at a point. ... Good luck!

Please confirm if the following interpretation is correct. A regular hexagon with inner radius $r_1$ and outer radius $R_1$ is originaly oriented so that one of its vertices points towards the centre of the equilateral triangle. The triangle has inner radius $r_2$ and outer radius $R_2$ and is also oriented with one vertex towards the centre of the hexagon (meaning, in this original situation they are not necessarily tangent).

Now for every angle $\theta_1$ we must try to find an angle $\theta_2$ such that the hexagon rotated clockwise over an angle $\theta_1$ and the triangle rotated clockwise over an angle $\theta_2$ have exactly one point in common, except possibly for some exceptional angles where they have coincident edges.

Lieven & Blue, thank you both. bear with me. I'm both new to this, and trying not to overwhelm with too much information that might also be irrelevant. I will add an image or three shortly. ( as soon as I figure out how to do so ) In the meantime, examples of what I mean are well illustrated on the righthand side of page 10 of the PDF located here - http://vintagemachinery.org/pubs/2186/3732.pdf Also, page 13 shows exactly what I am trying to ultimately accomplish. But I need to figure out how to calculate the tool form required to get there, first.

Lieven, yes, I do believe that you understand my intent. (:>)

If you do that with polygons and one of them rotates uniformly then the other one will typically swing back and forth.

Lieven, I'm not following what you mean by "swing back and forth." In concept, the rolling action of the two should just continue, endlessly. In real life application ( in my case anyway ) they are geared to each other. ( whether by actual, physical gearing or by servo motor gearing ) This was accomplished nearly a hundred years ago by men and women with slide rules. Sadly, I have been largely unable to find much text about the design process. We have worked out a way to design the Involutes, but other geometric shapes escape my grasp. I need help finding the math to accomplish it.

Are you aware of the existence of this series of books about all sorts of mechanical designs by Artobolevski, in fact the first one in a series of (at least) five ?

Jean Marie, I was not aware of of that author specifically, but have several books of very similar nature from the 1920s-1990s. One of my favorites is Ingenius Mechanisms ( isbn 0831110848 ) None of them (including the one you reference) seem to cover the math of what I am searching for, though. Have I overlooked it?

Lieven or anyone else that understands my quest - Is there a way to describe this mathematically? Even if only in one angular condition. I might be able to use something like Excel Solver to iterate that for a range of angular conditions. Thank you in advance for any guidance.
